# Removing the first element from a queue C++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to remove the first element of the Queue but, this does not seem to work. Here is my code:

```
struct List {
    //string name;
    double price;
    List* next; 
};
List* head = NULL; List* tail = NULL;
struct queue
{
    List* head, * tail;
};
void printAll()
{
    cout << "Data in the queue:\t";
    for (List* temp = head; temp != NULL; temp = temp->next)
    {
        cout << temp->price << "\t";

        if (temp->next == NULL)
        {
            delete temp; // here I don’t know how to write it down
        }
}
```

Comment: "Does not seem to work" is not a sufficiently detailed diagnostic. Do you get an error? Does it crash? Will it compile?

Comment: In C++ try and use `nullptr` in preference to C's `NULL`.

Comment: Did you add anything to the queue? Also why are you deleting the last node? Remove the entire `if` block and end the for loop

Comment: This is an incomplete example and is missing important context, like what Amal is asking about.

Comment: To remove first element you should set head to head->next and after that delete previous head.

Comment: Basically your remove the last element but forget to set the previous `temp->next` to `NULL` resulting by a dangled pointer here.
BTW, is it c++ code ? I suggest you to use standard container which is far better than current implementation in average.

Comment: Why are you trying to remove items from your queue in a function called `printAll`? This function should be printing the queue, it should not be destroying the queue as well.

Answer (score 3):

Remember that using existing containers is much easier to get results. In this case, removing the oldest entry in a `std::queue` would be `if (! myQueue.empty()) myQueue.pop();` with added safety that there is actually to delete.

However, to learn programming, it makes sense to make your own containers and there are even circumstances where own containers perform better, so about your question: when changing anything in a linked list, the pointers have to be updated to still have a consistent linked list, so to remove an entry, the pointer to the entry has to point to the next entry and then the selected entry can be deleted. In case of the first entry, that's the one that head is pointing to, so just point to that with a temporary pointer, let the head pointer point to what the first entry is pointing to and then you can safely delete the first entry via the temporary pointer.

If in your example, you actually fill the queue at the head side and remove at the tail side, you would always need to iterate to find the last but one element to set its pointer to null and let tail point to it. This is not a good idea on a singly linked list. Fill at the tail and remove at the head side.

Also, make sure to not change data in "print"-functions. Make functions predictable by not doing more than is announced by the name. A better name for the current function could be "finishExample" or "processQueue" which can do an output and cleanup.

If you feel like cheating, or need some inspiration, this gives an example implementation: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/queue-linked-list-implementation/ where `enQueue()` fills and `deQueue()` removes. (I just googled an example, so I can't say how good it actually is.)